# Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Set<String>' operands Error

Tags: arrays, swift, string, set

I have 2 Arrays and I want to merge them after converting them to Sets, this is my code:

```
var before = Array(Set(beforevalues))
var first = Array(Set(myvalues))


let save1 = first{ ($0.rangeOfString("today") != nil) }
let save2 = Set(save1)
var mynewarray = Set(save2)

let merge = Array(Set(before + mynewarray)) // THIS LINE ERROR
```

but it gives:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Set' operands

How can I fix it?

Comment: That's because there is no `+` operator for sets ... You'll find everything you need on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set (Hint: It is a "union")

Comment: @MartinR yeah i know but i want to merge thats ? How ?

Comment: The error seems to be misleading. It's a type mismatch: `before` is `Array`, `mynewarray` is `Set`. Possibly `Array(Set(before + save1))` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `union` to merge two `Set`s as there's no `+` operator defined for `Set`s. Moreover, `before` is an `Array` while `mynewarray` is a `Set`, but since `Set.union` accepts an input argument of type `Sequence` you can solve that issue by calling `union` on the `Set`.

```
let merged = Array(mynewarray.union(before))
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree with [Dávid Pásztor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038214/5501940), I would mention that you could override the plus operator `+` for Sets to let it do the desired functionality (union):

```
extension Set {
    static func +(lhs: Set, rhs: Set) -> Set {
        return lhs.union(rhs)
    }
}
```

therefore, you would be able to:

```
var first = Set(["hi", "greeting", "hello"])
var second = Set(["greeting", "hello", "hello", "hey"])

let merged = Array(Set(first + second)) // ["hi", "hey", "greeting", "hello"]
```

which should be also workable for your case.